# We shouldn't answer homework question directly, should we?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

Taking [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714397/315444) as example, where [someone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/714408/315444) solved the problem for the author whereas mine was related to hint (cause there's some steps left to think/solve). But -1 on my answer is for what? Solving a homework question isn't our goal. IIRC, it's (solving homework for someone) against the rules also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the question is closed (and obviously close-worthy under our homework-and-exercises policy), I would submit that no one should have answered the question in the first place, full answer or not. I see no point in litigating individual votes on answers to off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am deleting it. :)